# Why ISIL is targeting Pakistani politicians?

Tags: terrorism, pakistan, islamic-state

I am asking this question in the context of recent Mastung and Bannu bombings in Pakistan, in which around 153 people were killed and 223 were injured:-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Mastung_and_Bannu_bombings

Comment: Are you looking for a link to the statement of ISIL claiming responsibility?

Comment: Don't have the links to actual sources (Hence the comment, not an answer), It's just the belief of the Salafist terrorists that Democracy is "Un-Islamic" and "Voting is haram" and that only Caliphate is acceptable form of government (Ironically they don't know that the first 4 Caliphs were Elected). They wanted to discourage people from voting.

Comment: @NSNoob 
I understand what you are saying, but then why only Pakistan? They could have targeted Turkey, Iran, Israel, Afghanistan, or other central asian countries which are closer to their base in Iraq.

Comment: @amsquareb They strike where they can strike. Baluchistan province of Pakistan is plagued with decades long insurgency, rebellion and now Islamist terrorism. They do the same in Afghanistan and rarely in Iran or Central Asian states. Turkey and Israel have much better security so they very rarely get hit.